# Azure search adding documents to index approaches

Tags: azure, search

I am not sure if i am going to be able to describe this right but ill give it a go.

We are working on implementing Azure search. At the core level we have searchable PDF documents that we want the text of them added to the index so all of them are searchable. 
The initial thought was to just submit that document to the index via the add document rest api.  The thinking was that this would be the most simple and quickest path 
to getting the text of that document into the index. We also considered using and indexer and just having all the Searchable PDF docs in a blob store and have the indexer 
crawl those every 10-15 mins.

We also looked into (based on a recommendation) submitting a standalone JSON file with the text from the PDF in it. Submitting that to the index either via the same add document API or 
placing that file in a blob store. Within the JSON document we would need to have document identifiers that provide the index with the location of the PDF so that when that text is found
via search, we can make that clickable and as a result open the PDF.

It seems to me that pushing in the json file with the document add api. Indexing that and when it is part of a search we can use the doc id to link back to it and open it.

For those of you that have used Azure search. How did you implement?

Answer (score 0):

If you're totally sure that only pdf will live on this particular index, then the first approach is faster to implement, since the native indexer can be used for extract the content of the pdf document as well to push it to the index.

Both approaches will work, but for the second one, you would need to extract the pdf yourself using an external tool.